# Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available

Tags: java, netty, grpc, aix, ibm-jdk

#### What version of gRPC are you using?

1.13.1

I am using java 8 to build an executable jar. Below is the java version:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-2~14.04-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I am using gradle 3.4.1 to generate the jar as follows:
`/opt/gradle-3.4.1/bin/gradle jar -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/`

Below are the dependencies defined in the module-level build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/commons-io-2.6.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/grpc-all.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/java-protobuf.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/jetty.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/log4j-core-2.8.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.20.Final.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/netty-tcnative-2.0.20.Final.jar")
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/picocli-3.8.2.jar")
  compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '20.0'
  compile files("$TOOLCHAIN_VERSION_DIR/lib/javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar")
  compile project(':annotation')
}
```

After building, I am running the jar on an AIX7.2 machine as follows:
`/usr/java8_64/jre/bin/java -jar agent-1.0.jar`

The java version on the AIX machine is as follows:

```
$ /usr/java8_64/jre/bin/java -version           
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.5.26 - pap6480sr5fp26-20181115_03(SR5 FP26))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 AIX ppc64-64-Bit Compressed References 20181106_401576 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - fde1d6f
OMR      - d8c3617
IBM      - 5c4a9f0)
JCL - 20181022_01 based on Oracle jdk8u191-b26
```

But I am getting the following error while running:

```
Feb 17, 2019 3:11:33 AM io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts defaultSslProvider
INFO: netty-tcnative unavailable (this may be normal)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64, netty_tcnative_ppc_64, netty_tcnative]
        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:430)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:97)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:242)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forServer(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.useTransportSecurity(NettyServerBuilder.java:456)
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.useTransportSecurity(NettyServerBuilder.java:55)
        at com.ankit.agents.AgentMain.<init>(AgentMain.java:91)
        at com.ankit.agents.AgentMain.main(AgentMain.java:132)
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85)
                ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64.a
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
                ... 10 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1425)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1395)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:565)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                        ... 10 more
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1425)
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1395)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:565)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
                                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:647)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                                ... 11 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative_ppc_64
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85)
                ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_ppc_64.a
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
                ... 10 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty_tcnative_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1425)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1395)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:565)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                        ... 10 more
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty_tcnative_ppc_64 (Not found in java.library.path)
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1425)
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1395)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:565)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
                                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:647)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                                ... 11 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load a native library: netty_tcnative
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:205)
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:85)
                ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative.a
                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:161)
                ... 10 more
                Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty_tcnative (Not found in java.library.path)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1425)
                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1395)
                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:565)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:243)
                        at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:124)
                        ... 10 more
                        Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: netty_tcnative (Not found in java.library.path)
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1425)
                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1395)
                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:565)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
                                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:263)
                                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:647)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:255)
                                at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:233)
                                ... 11 more

Feb 17, 2019 3:11:33 AM io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts defaultSslProvider
INFO: Conscrypt not found (this may be normal)
Feb 17, 2019 3:11:33 AM io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts defaultSslProvider
INFO: Jetty ALPN unavailable (this may be normal)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:403)
        at io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:64)
        at io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.getJettyAlpnUnavailabilityCause(JettyTlsUtil.java:75)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:255)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forServer(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.useTransportSecurity(NettyServerBuilder.java:456)
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.useTransportSecurity(NettyServerBuilder.java:55)
        at com.ankit.agents.AgentMain.<init>(AgentMain.java:91)
        at com.ankit.agents.AgentMain.main(AgentMain.java:132)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative, Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.defaultSslProvider(GrpcSslContexts.java:256)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:171)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forServer(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.useTransportSecurity(NettyServerBuilder.java:456)
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.useTransportSecurity(NettyServerBuilder.java:55)
        at com.ankit.agents.AgentMain.<init>(AgentMain.java:91)
        at com.ankit.agents.AgentMain.main(AgentMain.java:132)
```

However, it is running fine on an Ubuntu machine. I am running the jar as follows:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar agent-1.0.jar`

The java version here is:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-2~14.04-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

What is the problem here and how to solve this?

Comment: AIX/PPC cannot use native code of Linux/x86.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond Do you know how can I build the required native code for AIX? I guess they are netty_tcnative_aix_ppc_64, netty_tcnative_ppc_64, netty_tcnative. On netty's github forum, I was told to compile the netty for AIX, but I am not sure how. Here is the link: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8871

Answer (score 7):

It could be that: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-with-netty-tcnative-on-boringssl

I added `runtime 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:2.0.25.Final'` in my build.gradle and it worked

Comment: And what was the OS on which you were able to run it?

Comment: I ran it on MacOs Mojave

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this in another similar question also, this issue can also be because of alpine base image incompaitibility if you are using it.

"Looks like you are using base image as alpine, which actually doesn't supports gRPC, you need to add the gcompact apk in your application. So, what you can do is : Using docker :"

```
RUN apk add gcompat
ENV LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libgcompat.so.0
```

Comment: Are you sure it was AIX OS?

Comment: Yes. Actually even after adding boringssl dependencies it doesn't resolves for a lot of guys. Because they use alpine os for a lighter base, and alpine lack compatibility with gRPC. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just updating the Java version from 8 to 14 solved the issue (version 11 should also be fine).

If you are on Intellij, make sure your version change worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Java 17 and the error is resolved.